# How to create a terrain in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I know, I have to create a plane with a lot of segments, but after that how to modify the y position of the vertices?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe you should try to use [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) for generating heightmap? Also there is [tutorial](http://grahamweldon.com/posts/view/3d-terrain-generation-with-three-js) with terrain generation using three.js.

Comment: That tutorial doesnt work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an example of that:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain.html

Comment: how does this work? is the ground regenerating after you get to the edge?

Comment: No it does not regenerate the landscape. You either have to do that yourself by making several meshes next to each other (which is better than having one huge mesh).